# How can I call one JavaScript function in another JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

```
function rblSelectedValue() {

    var radio = document.getElementsByName('rblInterview');
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked == true) {
            // document.getElementById('txt1').value = radio[i].value;

            var value1 = radio[i].value
            var radio1 = document.getElementsByName('rblPrefBatch');
            radio1[i].value = value1;
            radio1[i].checked = true;
            // alert(radio[i].value);

        }

    }

}

function ForNext(ctrlid) 
{
    var DdlYear = document.getElementById("<%= DdlYear.ClientID %>")

    if (document.getElementById(ctrlid).checked)
         {

            document.getElementById('<%=PanelView.ClientID %>').style.visibility = 'visible';
            // rblSelectedValue();
            document.getElementById('<%=txtpreYearofAppearing.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtYearofAppearing.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtpreupscrollno.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtRollno.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtaddidpre.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtAddID.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtaddyearpre.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=DdlYear.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtpreNoOfAttempt2009.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtNoOfPrevAttempts.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPrePrelim.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtPrelimi.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtpremain.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtMain.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtpregs.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtGS.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtpreopt.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtOptional.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=rblPreint.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=rblInterview.ClientID%>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtpreother.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtCorseothers.ClientID%>').value;

        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById('<%=PanelView.ClientID %>').style.visibility = 'hidden';

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

its a simple function call like

```
rblSelectedValue();
```

but just include both javascript file in html page.

Comment: can i call rbselectvalue() in fornext()?

Answer (score 0):

```
function one(){
//code
}

function two(){
//more code
one(); //calling function "one"
}
```

Comment: Put an alert in both functions and then call both the functions one by one to check if they are working. May be you missed some bracket or something ..
http://jsfiddle.net/LDpay/

Comment: plz can u tell me in brief??

Comment: You will have to check if your functions are working.. 
I suggest that you place `alert("i am inside rblSelectedValue");` inside rblSelectedValue function and `alert("inside ForNext");` inside your ForNext somewhere. Now put a button on somewhere to on click of which you execute ForNext to check if there is any problem with the ForNext if an alert msg shows up then its working fine do the same with your other function. If both the functions are working individually you can easilu call one function from another the way i suggested. Go to the link i gave to understand what i am saying.